# I have a subset and I am trying to extract values from a specific row in order to use quantiles in "R"

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, subset, quantile

*The subset has many values different rows but for my purpose, I only use one*

**Current Code**

```
male <- subset(dropped, SEXP == 2)
female <- subset(dropped, SEXP == 1)
incomeMale <- subset(male, TOTINCP > 0)
#a vector called percentIncome of all the values in the row TOTINCP from incomeMale

quantile(percentIncome, 0.05,0.10,0.95,0.90)
```

I want a vector of all the values in TOTINCP so that I can use the quantiles function to get the percentages of the bottom 5%, 10% and top 5%, 10% .
I tried using nrows() but it doesn't take in the subset of incomeMale so it would just be giving me all the values in TOTINCP.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand exactly what you're looking for without a reproducible example, but here's an outline of how to do something similar with the iris data set:

```
#Using the iris data set, limit to one species
subset(iris, Species == "virginica")

#Get a vector of the Sepal Width for one species
subset(iris, Species == "virginica")$Sepal.Width

#Get quantiles for the Sepal Width for one species
quantile(subset(iris, Species == "virginica")$Sepal.Width, c(0.05, 0.1, 0.9, 0.95))
```